# Dell E6520 ubuntu 11.10 64bit no working vga / dvi

Tags: 11.10, dell, nvidia-optimus

I can't get any external monitor to work with my dell E6520 after an upgrade. from 11.04 -> 11.10, which is pretty damn annoying. I got a second monitor to work for a short moment once. Currently The nvidia settings manager does not propperly configure any external monitor reliable. It just goes back to the old configuration after 15 seconds. It used to work before..

My actions so far:

- Updated the bios to the newest version.
- Installed ironhide with and without optimus enabled.
- installed nvidia drivers

I found somewhere that the 32bit version of ubuntu is fully supported on the dell E6520. Should I switch and start using that?

Think I will wait until the next version before I waste another few hours or so on fixing this. since the next version of ubuntu got improved graphics stuff coming.

*update* fixed almost all my issues using the default opensource drivers. I can't get my hdmi port to work (yet) but the vga port works now again. yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succesfully got all my vga/hdmi ports working on 12.04 using the propertierty drivers from nvidia.

NOTE: disable optimus in the bios!

I installed the driver in this way:

1. Download the 64bit nividia driver.
2. control - alt F6, or F7.. to get into a terminal screen.
3. cd to the direcotry you downloaded the driver
4. `sudo service lightdm stop` ( this stops all X / graphics stuff currently running)
5. `sudo sh ./NVIDIA-your-version driver.`
6. follow the intructions of the installation.
7. `sudo service lightdm start` ( now your login screen should show up)

Now you are running the nvidia driver and using nvidia settings you can configure all your screens. NOTE: It could be that you have to reinstall the driver after a kernel update..

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug already opened for your problem and I think you should mark it as affected in order to be solved it as soon as possible; the bug affects unity and the nvidia driver, so I don't think that installing Ubuntu 32-bit could solve the problem:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/864784

I also found that you should solve it temporarily logging with unity-2d.
If you don't want to use unity-2d, you can try any of the solutions suggested in this thread of ubuntuforums:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859730&page=5

Answer (score 0):

[Some folks posted a solution to the Ubuntu Forums regarding this same laptop](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1726575) -- though it depends on your video card (run `lspci | grep -i vga` in a terminal).

Comment: I had a 'perfect' working configuration. except maybe a little short battery life. After an upgrade to latest ubuntu, and i waited 2 months or so before doing that, using external monitors broke down when using compiz / 3d. not the end of the world but annoying.